# What protocols do I need to read along to make sure I don't miss any traffic and cover all the communication from the web browser?

Tags: browser, network-protocols, websocket, webrtc

For a university project, I need to record all the traffic that a web browser sends to a server. The goal is to find the input that the user made on the website in the resulting traffic. The project assumes that user input can also be sent obfuscated, so I need to consider all possible protocols or transport paths that a browser can use.

Currently, I use a browser extension for this and already cover HTTP(S), WebSockets, and WebRTC.

My understanding is that these are all the protocols that a browser can use to communicate with a web server, since XMPP implementations, for example, would use WebSockets. But unfortunately, I can't find any source to back this up. Is my assumption correct at all?

If anyone could explain to me why I'm wrong/ right and maybe would even provide me some link to a citable source this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Look at Fiddler or a simmillar debugging proxy. that will cover the web protocols you have, but also show you any you may have missed. it will also allow you to configure TLS/SSL proxy, so you can see the difference between HTTP and HTTPS, which sounds like its the point of this project. you can filter the fiddler output to show only connections made by particular processes, so you can tell the diff between the traffic you want to see and that which you don't. https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Note that the reason I suggest using a proxy to discover it for yourself is that there is no rule or law that constrains what traffic might emit from a browser. obviously the most common will be HTTP containing markup/style/script content over TCP, but there are many potential network protocols they might use. there will never be a cannonical list of the protocols that a generic-unspecified browser is limited to.

Comment: As a school project, I'd expect the necessary information was provided during the class or in the curriculum. Have you spoken w/ your prof regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question is answerable as written - the communications paths/methods are controlled more by server then the browser, so it depends on if the question implies a specific server under your control or not.

Similarly the scope of what can be done with a browser will depend on the browser.  A couple of things you may/may not have considered.   Some things that spring to mind include the use of QUIC/UDP protocol rather then http(s), and extensions like ftp.  DNS (and DoH)  may be another way that data can leak.

It may be useful to use something like tcpdump or another libpcap client or equivalent to see the traffic on the wire to see where traffic is actually being sent.